# Why does {a_n}/{a_(n+1)} >= {b_n}/{b_(n+1)} imply {a_n} <= k*{b_n}?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Where {a_n} and {b_n} are two positive-term series and k is a real number (and for n big enough).
I was reviewing my calc II notes, and got stuck in Raabe's Test, because I didn't catch the proof well, and wherever I find something about it, it's always about p-series and the fact that's on the question title is constantly used. I can't find anything, and I've tried something simillar to the usual proof for Comparison Test. But I don't get to prove it. I'd appreciate some ideas to enlighten me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \ge \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}$ is equivalent to $\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} \le \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ if all the $a$'s and $b$'s are positive.

Comment: Thank you, rather than considering the quotient sequence I was trying to find conditions for a_n. Now I see that {a_n/b_n} is decreasing, and therefore, for n big enough there must exist a positive real number k such that a_n/b_n ≤ k. And that means: a_n ≤ k*b_b for n big enough.